# How to make it so my program doesn't ask for input twice?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I'm using the `Scanner` class in Java and I ran into an issue where my program would do something like this:

```java
public static void answer() {
    System.out.print("\t> ");
    command = scan.nextLine(); // It needs to be able to read the full line to be able to capture spaces
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (!command.contains("Hello World!")) {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
        answer();
    }
}
```

But would print this:

```
Hello!!
    > Hello!!
(user input)
```

So, after some research, I decided to change my program to be something like this:

```java
public static void answer() {
    scan.nextLine(); // new piece
    System.out.print("\t> ");
    command = scan.nextLine();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (!command.contains("Hello World!")) {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
        answer();
    }
}
```

This led to a different problem. If the user messes up their input by typing something like "fjbejwkb" instead of "Hello World!", this would happen:

```
Hello!!
    > fjbejwkb (user inputs wrong thing)
Hello!!
(user input)
    > (user input)
```

If I get rid of my added `scan.nextLine()`, I return to my original problem of "Hello!!" being printed twice but if I leave it, whenever I use the `answer()` method after its first use it will force the user to type in two things. While the first isn't read, I'm sure this could lead to some confusion which I'd like to avoid.

I've tried using `println` / `\n` instead of `scan.nextLine()` but this is visually unappealing to me:

```
Hello!!

    > (user input)
```

I've also tried `command = scan.next()` instead of `command = scan.nextLine()` but this does not capture spaces - which for the problem I'm working on I need.

Here's what I want:

```
Hello!!
    > fjbejwkb (user inputs wrong thing)
Hello!!
    > (user input)
```

When the user inputs the wrong thing, it should ask for input once and then ask for input again.

Comment: In your condition, `!command.contains(" Hello World!")`, do you intend for that space to be before Hello? Additionally, where is your `command` variable that both `answer()` and `main()` can see it?

Comment: Why are you removing tabs and right angle brackets from `command`? Those are in the prompt you display, but presumably they won't be in what the user types?

Comment: @it'sjayway I kind of assumed the scanner scanned the whole line, not just what the user inputted - so that's why I did that.

Comment: @DavidConrad I assumed the scanner would read the whole line

Comment: The Scanner only reads the input the user types.

Comment: @DavidConrad Okay, I've removed those segments from my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) (rather than `while`):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeloWrld {
    private static Scanner  scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String  command;

    public static void answer() {
        System.out.print("\t> ");
        command = scan.nextLine(); // It needs to be able to read the full line to be able to capture spaces
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Hello!!");
            answer();
        } while (!command.contains("Hello World!"));
        System.out.println("Good bye.");
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run of the above code:

```
Hello!!
    > fjbejwkb
Hello!!
    > Hello World!
Good bye.
```

Comment: Thank you! This did end up working (with a little workaround).